# How to add prefix to list items only if prefix is not there already?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to add 'p' only if that prefix is missing, I am trying to get `['pa', 'pb', 'pc']`, I am using python3.6

```
>>> l=['a','b','pc']
>>> ['p'+x for x in l]
['pa', 'pb', 'ppc']
>>>
>>> ['p'+x for x in l if not x.startswith('p')]
['pa', 'pb']
```

Comment: `['p'+x if not x.startswith('p') else x for x in l]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
['p' + x for x in l if x[0] != 'p']
```

Sorry, that gives the same as yours, if you want all three then try.

```
['p' + x if x[0] != 'p' else x for x in l]
```

Comment: OP has to remember that it's dealing with strings, which are just arrays of characters. Good job @cmxu

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
new_list = ['p'+x for x in l if x[0]!="p"] + [x for x in l if x[0]=="p"]
```

or in one line :

```
new_list = ['p' + x if not x[0] == 'p' else x for x in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this, if you don't want to save in a new list:

```
for x in l:
    if(x[0]!='p'):
        l[l.index(x)]='p'+x
```

Comment: Should use `enumerate` to get index of list element, rather than `l[l.index(x)]`. Also, you should use `str.startswith()`, rather than `x[0] != 'p'`